# How to programmatically change React Router page status?

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, routes, http-status-code-404, react-router

So, I have a relatively complex setup involving react-router and react-async-connect to render stuff server-side.

Here's my route setup:

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>

  <Route path='profile/:userID' component={UserProfile} />

  <Route path='*' component={NotFound} status={404} />

</Route>
```

So, when someone hits a `profile/{userID}` path, obviously the UserProfile component is rendered, which in turn makes a call to an external API to get props. However, if this API returns a 404, I want to display my 404 page.

The trouble is that it's a 404 from an external service, not a "real" router 404. How does one trigger this?

I really want to avoid importing the NotFound component into UserProfile component and doing it that way, seems quite dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `browserHistory` function:

```js
// UserProfile.js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// In place where you need redirect to 404:
browserHistory.push('/404-page')
```

I think, you can redirect to any route that don't matches your defined routes, as you are redirecting to `NotFound` page at every not matched route.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to retain the functionality in the example I gave, where the route is preserved and the 404 component is rendered.

Comment: @JohnDoe, you want to render `NotFound` component, not changing the route, ex. saving `profile/:userID` pathname?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @JohnDoe, what flux lib you are using?

Comment: Redux, based on [this boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

Comment: @JohnDoe did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

- Keep your 404 application status in store/reducer as default `false`.
- Upon getting 404 status code - set it to `true`.
- Once user is clicked other link - reset to `false`.
- In your `App.render()` do smth like this:

`render() {
  return isNotFound ? <NotFound /> : {this.props.children};
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this library, [react-server-status](https://github.com/vgno/react-server-status), that provides a friendly and easier way to provide the status page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ServerStatus from 'react-server-status';

export default class NotFound extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ServerStatus status={ 404 }>
                <div>Some content</div>
            </ServerStatus>
        );
    }
}
```